# Fatal error: msgsps_common.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, include-path

When I tried build my C project using MQTT (MOSQUITTO) I received this error: "

```
make all 
Building file: ../mosquitto/test/msgsps_pub.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I"/home/procifalus/workspace/C-Cplusplus/protheus/mosquitto" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"mosquitto/test/msgsps_pub.d" -MT"mosquitto/test/msgsps_pub.d" -o "mosquitto/test/msgsps_pub.o" "../mosquitto/test/msgsps_pub.c"
../mosquitto/test/msgsps_pub.c:9:27: fatal error: msgsps_common.h: No such file or directory
 #include <msgsps_common.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
mosquitto/test/subdir.mk:45: recipe for target 'mosquitto/test/msgsps_pub.o' failed
make: *** [mosquitto/test/msgsps_pub.o] Error 1".
```

Could someone help me ?

Comment: Have you been able to locate the header file on your system?

Comment: Should you be using `-I"/home/procifalus/workspace/C-Cplusplus/protheus/mosquitto/include"` for the directory containing the header?

Comment: If you are talking about link mosquittolib to eclipse. Yes I did.

Have no directory "/include" in mosquitto. Mosquitto directory is the root of my mosquitto archives (headers), I have others sub directories inside mosquitto. All headers are in it.